# Terraform Docker Unable to Authorize Private Docker Hub Images

Tags: docker, terraform, dockerhub

I have been trying to authenticate and access the latest tag of a private Docker Hub registry image without any luck for a couple of days now.

```
provider "docker" {
  host = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"

  registry_auth {
    address  = "index.docker.io"
    username = var.docker_username
    password = var.docker_password
  }
}

data "docker_registry_image" "frontend" {
  name = "<username>/<image_name>:<image_tag>"
}

resource "docker_image" "frontend" {
  name          = data.docker_registry_image.frontend.name
  pull_triggers = [data.docker_registry_image.frontend.sha256_digest]
}
```

Planning failed. Terraform encountered an error while generating this plan.

```
╷
│ Error: Got error when attempting to fetch image version <username>/<image_name>:<image_tag> from registry: Got bad response from registry: 401 Unauthorized
│ 
│   with module.kubernetes.data.docker_registry_image.frontend,
│   on modules/kubernetes/docker.tf line 29, in data "docker_registry_image" "frontend":
│   29: data "docker_registry_image" "frontend" {
```

I've replaced real parameters with /<image_name>:<image_tag> for demonstration purposes.

I've tried https://index.docker.io/v1/, registry-1.docker.io, registry.hub.docker.com, and many other registries without any luck. It's getting frustrating at this point.

Has anybody had any luck with pulling official Docker Hub private images?